# Find the max value at each row - Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, max

I have a dataframe where I would like to find max value of each row between **1** and **5** values.

Condition 1 to 5: Columns -> A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1, J1

Find Max_Value: Columns -> A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2, J2

**Max_Value** (Column) is the expected output on the screenshot.

You may see the attached screenshot to understand the question better.
Thanks in advance for your support!

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'ID': [1212, 2342, 2421], 
'A1': [1, 1, 1], 'A2': [0.3, 0.004, 0.86], 'B1': [2, 1.5, 3],       
'B2': [0.1, 0.8, 0.005], 'C1': [3, 2, 5], 'C2': [0.8, 0.2, 0.3],
'D1': [4, 2.5, 7], 'D2': [0.2, 0.4, 0.004], 'E1': [5, 3, 9],        
'E2': [0.9, 0.005, 0.99], 'F1': [6, 3.5, 11], 'F2': [0.4, 0.3, 0.4],
'G1': [7, 5, 13], 'G2': [0.6, 0.85, 0.003], 'H1': [8, 4.5, 15],     
'H2': [0.94, 0.088, 0.85], 'J1': [9, 5, 17], 'J2': [0.003, 0.0001,0.3]})
print(df)
```

Comment: have a look at  [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the code below:

```
mask = df.filter(regex=r'[A-Z]1').stack().between(1, 5).values
df['MAX'] = df.filter(regex=r'[A-Z]2').stack()[mask].groupby(level=0).max()
```

> The expected result for the first row: 0,9 (1 and 5 values are between A1 and E2). The expected result for the second row: 0,85 (1 and 5 values are between A1 and J2). The expected result for the third row: 0,86 (1 and 5 values are between A1 and C2)

```
>>> df
  Type    ID  A1     A2  ...  J1      J2   MAX
0    X  1212   1  0.300  ...   9  0.0030  0.90
1    Y  2342   1  0.004  ...   5  0.0001  0.85
2    Z  2421   1  0.860  ...  17  0.3000  0.86

[3 rows x 21 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pd.DataFrame.max` function with the parameter `axis=1`.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4,6], 'b': [3,4,5], 'c': [1,7,2]})

    # Select first 5 columns
    df = df.iloc[: , :5]

    # Get max per row
    maxValuesObj = pd.DataFrame({'max': df.max(axis=1)})
    
    # Assign column values
    maxValuesObj['column'] = df.columns.values
    
    print(maxValuesObj)

        | max    | column
    0   | 3      | a
    1   | 7      | b
    2   | 6      | c
```

Comment: Edited to properly take first 5 columns

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, It does not solve the problem. Because, respectively A1&A2, B1&B2... are a group. So, I would like to find the highest decimal value between 1 and 5 values. Pay attention that 1 is always on the column A1 but the value 5 is not under a  specific column. This makes the question a little bit tricky. You may have a look at again to the screenshot that I have attached above. Example: For the first row,  the search should be done between A1 and E2 columns and then find the highest decimal value.